# Sending data to a hosted payment page failing url array - amount is a string, it expects a decimal value

Tags: javascript, wordpress, checkout

Client has a wordpress website with an order form that collects name, address, order value, this data then needs to be sent to a hosted payment page for customer to enter payment info.

Currently the url array looks like this -

****host-address****/payment?payment_amount=payment_amount&customer_surname=Name&customer_email=Email&customer_title=Title&customer_address_line1=Address&customer_address_town=Town&customer_address_postcode=Postcode&customer_address_country=Country

problem: its not sending the data properly, hosted payment page provider said "the payment_amount is a string, it expects a decimal value"

Is there an easier way to send the contents of a form to a HPP? or if not, how do i convert string to decimal when the order value varies?

Comment: Could you provide an example of the data you are sending?

Comment: its a wordpress form with these field ids

payment_amount
customer_surname
customer_email
customer_title
customer_address_line
customer_address_town
customer_address_postcode
customer_address_country
return_url


payment_amount         <------------------- this is the field I am stuck on, convert to decimal AND whats call i should use if the price is variable? 

I thought it was payment_amount={{payment_amount}}

AS its a wordpress form builder I need to somehow echo the price in the url string to the hosted payment page

Comment: Do verify `payment_amount` is printing out a number with a dot notation and not with a comma

Answer (score -1):

to convert String to number use this method in php

```
<?php 

$num = "1000.314"; 

// Convert string in number using  
// number_format(), function 
echo number_format($num), "\n"; 

// Convert string in number using  
// number_format(), function 
echo number_format($num, 2); 
?>
```

Comment: `PHP` uses type juggling as seen [here](https://ideone.com/tgXMZM)

Comment: its a wordpress form builder plugin - these field ids I need to send to the hosted payment page:

payment_amount
customer_surname
customer_email
customer_title
customer_address_line
customer_address_town
customer_address_postcode
customer_address_country
return_url


payment_amount         <------------------- this is the field I am stuck on, convert to decimal AND whats call i should use if the price is variable? 

I thought it was payment_amount={{payment_amount}}

AS its a wordpress form builder I need to somehow echo the price in the url string to the hosted payment page